# PostgreSQL uninstalling-reinstalling: maintscripts-functions missing

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-22.04

I have followed this tutorial to remove PostgreSQL : https://www.squash.io/step-by-step-process-to-uninstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu/

Then I tried to reinstall it with sudo apt-get -y install postgresql.

The following error occurs:

```
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  postgresql-client-12
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  postgresql-16 postgresql-common
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql postgresql-16 postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 18,2 MB/18,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 60,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-16 amd64 16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1 [18,1 MB]
Get:2 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql all 16+257.pgdg22.04+1 [69,2 kB]
Fetched 18,2 MB in 2s (9 434 kB/s)    
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-common.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-15' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 283693 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-common_257.pgdg22.04+1_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Unpacking postgresql-common (257.pgdg22.04+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-16_16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 11: .: cannot open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions: No such file
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-16_16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new postgresql-16 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_16+257.pgdg22.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (16+257.pgdg22.04+1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-16_16.2-1.pgdg22.04+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.04, trying to reinstall postgresql-16.

I tried

sudo apt-get clean,

sudo apt autoremove,

sudo apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-client-common.

sudo apt remove --purge postgresql-common

sudo apt-get -f install postgresql-client-common

sudo apt-get -f --fix-broken install postgresql-common

Nothing works until now.

Thanks a lot for the help !